# memcpy equivalent in php

Tags: php, memcpy

I want to send a UDP message over a network in PHP. 
The message has a predefined protocol say the message must be 10 bytes long, in which the first 3 bytes are for entry 1, 2 bytes for entry 2, 3 bytes are for entry 3, and the last 2 bytes for entry 4.

How can I do this in PHP?
As in C we can use memcpy.

Comment: Simply reusing the array will do?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to convert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a string of the required bytes. A character of a string is a byte in PHP.

Comment: but the message contains different types like intergers, strings etc. for example i want to insert an integer value for entry 2 whic is 2 bytes long and the integer value is something like 1207 (4 bytes, as a character of a string is a byte in php)

Answer (score 0):

I really wish there was a fast way to do this in PHP! All the PHP string functions
return a string rather than allow you to directly copy into an existing string.
The latter is extremely useful from a memory perspective if you have megabyte -
sized arrays. The following code is a PHP variant of the kind of thing I would like... 
It would be nice if you could do this kinda manipulation directly in PHP as a native
function call rather than have to make your own extension. In the below,
$source is a short string we would like to copy over part of the data in the
much longer string $destination. We pass the latter by reference so we don't
waste memory by doing the function call.

```
function charCopy($source, &$destination, $start, $length)
{
    $endk = intval($length - 1);
    $end = intval($start + $endk);
    $start = intval($start);
    for($j = $end, $k = $endk; $j >= $start; $j--, $k--) {
        $destination[$j] = $source[$k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is close.

```
function &memcpy(&$dest,$src,$n){
$dest=substr($src,0,$n) . substr($dest,$n);
return $dest;
}
```

note that unlike C, PHP manage memory & realloc for you, and you can't overflow :p i don't think you can make an exact memcpy clone in userland, you could throw some exceptions / trigger_error() if $n > strlen($src) or $n>strlen($dest) ofc. the code above will just automatically rezie $dest for you, if needed, unlike C's memcpy.